# Compilation error "Cannot find symbol" on DriverManager.getConnection()

Tags: java

```
    import java.io.FileInputStream;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.sql.Connection;
import java.sql.DriverManager;
import java.util.Properties;
import java.util.logging.Level;
import java.util.logging.Logger;

public class Jdbc {

    public static void main(String args[]) {



        FileInputStream in = null;
        Connection con = null;
        try {

            Properties props = new Properties();
            in = new FileInputStream("/external/configuration/dir/db.properties");
            props.load(in);
            in.close();
            String driver = props.getProperty("jdbc.driver");
            if (driver != null) {
                Class.forName(driver);
            }
            String host = props.getProperty("jdbc.host");
            String port = props.getProperty("jdbc.port");
            String database = props.getProperty("jdbc.database");
            String username = props.getProperty("jdbc.username");
            String password = props.getProperty("jdbc.password");
            con = DriverManager.getConnection(host,port,database,username, password);
        } catch (Exception ex) {
            Logger.getLogger(Jdbc.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        } finally {
            if (in != null) {
                try {
                    in.close();
                } catch (IOException ex) {
                    Logger.getLogger(Jdbc.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
                }
            }
            if (con != null) {
                try {
                    con.close();
                } catch (Exception ex) {
                    Logger.getLogger(Jdbc.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
                }
            }

        }
    }
}
```

The Error is:

1 error

```
C:\Users\Desktop>javac Jdbc.java
Jdbc.java:32: cannot find symbol
symbol  : method getConnection(java.lang.String,java.lang.String,java.lang.Strin
g,java.lang.String,java.lang.String)
location: class java.sql.DriverManager
            con = DriverManager.getConnection(host,port,database,username, passw
ord);
```

Comment: Can you post the error messages ?

Comment: Error messages are needed. + make sure using those credentials from that machine are you able to connect to mysql using any client tool ?

Comment: please see the error mesg in the updated question.

Comment: You are doing mistakes related to the Java file. Please correct the Java related issues first.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is compiling version of your program .
Try to make out difference.
main things are **import**, **exception handling**

```
import java.io.FileInputStream;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.sql.Connection;
import java.sql.DriverManager;
import java.util.Properties;
import java.util.logging.Level;
import java.util.logging.Logger;

public class Jdbc {

    public static void main(String args[]) {



        FileInputStream in = null;
        Connection con = null;
        try {

            Properties props = new Properties();
            in = new FileInputStream("/external/configuration/dir/db.properties");
            props.load(in);
            in.close();
            String driver = props.getProperty("jdbc.driver");
            if (driver != null) {
                Class.forName(driver);
            }
            String url = props.getProperty("jdbc.url");
            String username = props.getProperty("jdbc.username");
            String password = props.getProperty("jdbc.password");
            con = DriverManager.getConnection(url, username, password);
        } catch (Exception ex) {
            Logger.getLogger(Jdbc.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        } finally {
            if (in != null) {
                try {
                    in.close();
                } catch (IOException ex) {
                    Logger.getLogger(Jdbc.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
                }
            }
            if (con != null) {
                try {
                    con.close();
                } catch (Exception ex) {
                    Logger.getLogger(Jdbc.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
                }
            }

        }
    }
}
```

Comment: awesome..it is working. But Now I have to execute it and I have to give the path location of my connector in the command prompt.

Comment: @shilps `But Now I have to execute it and I have to give the path location of my connector in the command prompt` Didn't get this

Comment: See, you have included only the url, username and password. But in my db.properties file, I have host,port, database-name,username,password. I removed the url and put the other things.But it is showing me the error. Can't I put the host and port no.  here?

Comment: @shilps I haven't changed that pattern its just same as you posted, btw if you have host port and db name you can form url for jdbc google it up.

Comment: I am not supposed to make changes in my db.properties file.....I have to do it in this way only

Comment: yeah....i was trying to make that run...but now its not working with my original code..:(

Comment: @shilps what is the error now, can you please post it in new Question if its actually another question

Comment: sir, the users of this site dont allow me to post a similar question. can you please give me your email id?I can email you...plz

Comment: @shilps :) if really its different question you can post it no body will close it. otherwise you can edit your question here

Comment: @shilps which error ?  can you please mark it differently, and have you used code given in my answer ?

Answer (score 3):

The code is not handling any checked exceptions like ClassNotFoundException, SQLException etc. in the code that is why the compiler is reporting errors.

Try surrounding the code in main method with try/catch block and compile the program. That should work.

Note: Provide complete information (errors that you are getting) so that others can help you in a better way.

Comment: +1 This is a much better answer style for homework questions that providing than providing explicit code.

Answer (score 0):

According to http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/connector-j-usagenotes-basic.html you should use `Class.forName(driver).newInstance();` instead of `Class.forName(driver);`.

Answer (score 0):

In my case `sbt run` worked fine and I got the error in `sbt test` because DriverManager.scala didn't find the jdbc driver:

> java.sql.SQLException: No suitable driver found for jdbc:postgresql

I solved this by adding the following line to the code (which is correctly using postgresql driver in run mode)

```
DriverManager.registerDriver(new org.postgresql.Driver());
```

I hope it helps.